# WeMos D1 rebooting 2-5 seconds into driving stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, esp8266, stepper-driver

I've set up a basic stepper motor rig with most commonly used components and L298n as a driver, WeMos D1 (ESP8266) as a controller: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQGPF.jpg

Programm is supposed to hit limit switch under the belt (works) and then move all the way to the top (reboots half way).

I've tried powering this up with a desktop power supply, and even powering stepper and WeMos with 2 separate batteries - same rebooting problem.

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: unplug the motor, then close the limit switch by hand. does it still reboot?

Comment: What does the board with the 7-segment readout do?  Possible noise or grounding problem...what voltages are you supplying with the power supply and/or batteries?  Grounds connected together?

Comment: To elaborate on jsotola's suggestion, since steppers are usually run open loop your system shouldn't be able to tell that the stepper isn't there - *unless* the problem is the power drawn by the stepper.  So run it without the motor and see if it works fine.  If not, software problem.  But if it does work without the motor, then probably the motor current is directly or inductively upsetting the system.

Comment: Huge thanks for your comments. They made me uncover the problem. After disconnecting WeMos and swapping it for a brand-new one, it was still rebooting - and problem was with the WDT as described in https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=442570.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my `loop()` was running too long and WeMos thought it's stuck. To solve this, I added `delay(1);` in relevant places.

```
#include <Stepper.h>

Stepper stepper(200, 5, 4, 0, 2);

void setup() {
  stepper.setSpeed(30);
  pinMode(16, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void home() {
  Serial.println("looking for home");
  while (digitalRead(16) == HIGH) {
    stepper.step(1);
    delay(1); // Prevent "Soft WDT reset"
  }
  while (digitalRead(16) == LOW) {
    stepper.step(-1);
    delay(1); // Prevent "Soft WDT reset"
  }
  Serial.println("at home");
}

void loop() {
  home();
  delay(1000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Serial.println("step " + String(i));
    stepper.step(-1);
    delay(1); // Prevent "Soft WDT reset"
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```